# How to plot a dataset

Tags: plotting

I have this data set and I imported them to Mathematica to analyze them using Import function. Now here I have only shown a part of the dataset just to give an example of how it looks in Excel.

[image]

Raw data is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQoIHOIzoF8MFFtavA5u6zYex-uawsH568xf2cbMpTQmKvSmd9GMXx2gLB1aCFwhPzpu5TTqkuUqq_L/pubhtml

Basically there is DrainI(i), DrainV(i), GateI(i), GateV(i) where GateV(i) is constant for =1,2,3,4....

Now I want to export this into Mathematica notebook and essentially plot DrainI(i) v/s DrainV(i) for different GateV(i) in the same plot.

This is how I do it:

```
ds = Import["Example_dataset.xlsx", "Dataset", 
   HeaderLines -> 1];
keypairs = {{"DrainI(1)", "DrainV(1)"}, {"DrainI(2)", "DrainV(2)"}};
idvd = Normal@ds[Values@*Transpose, keypairs];
idvdnew = 
 MapAt[#*20 &, 
  idvd, {All, All, 2}]; (*Convert to A/mm*)
ListLinePlot[idvdnew , 
 PlotLegends -> Defer /@ keypairs, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DS\)]\)(V)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(d\)]\)(A/mm)"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 0.03}}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15} , 
 ImageSize -> 400, FrameStyle -> Black]
```

But this is not plotting the desired output. What is going wrong over here? I think I am using the right commands.

Comment: To get helpful answers you should provide your data too!

Comment: I have added the data!

Comment: Are the values in `idvnew` all numeric and stored as a 1D array?  Try listing the first few such as `idvnew[[1;;10]]`.  Are they displayed as numbers without error?  Can you add two of them like `myval=idvnew[[1]]+idvnew[[2]]` again without error?   Get that right then just `ListLinePlot[idvnew]` to get that much working first.

Comment: I think the problem is with idvd itself. For some reason the dataset is not able to select out the keypairs.